# How to ignore error: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Store Root doesn't exists

Tags: https, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin for creating Monodroid app. 
My communication with backend is going over https protocol. That leads to "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Store Root doesn't exists" error in debug mode which is quate annoying. If I hit "Continue" everything goes well.

I have two questions here:
1. why this error occurs. My backend has valid certificate and https connection could be established from other clients without any issues.
2. How can I ignore this error (actually warning I think) if there is no way to fix that?

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer to this? I am currently having the same issue

Comment: I had a similar issue and it's solved by adding `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;` before sending any requests.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't seem to make a difference. the exception still appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [discussion](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2866/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-store-root-doesn-t-exists)  in Xamarin Developer Center with the last post on 16 July 2013 and no rersponse how to fix it.

And the [second one](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2063/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-store-root-doesn-t-exists) also in Xamarin Developer Center.
This time TS wrote:

> But when it happens (twice ever so far) it happened for multiple calls
>   in a row over a minute or two of debugging - but didn't happen when we
>   restarted the app. So it felt more like something was wrong within the
>   app rather than on server side...

There is also a registered [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12106) in Xamarin Bugzilla with **SSL Exception when connection google-based API** Title and its not affects iOS.

**To summarise:**

as for today there is no solution for it, but you can observe the links shown and maybe also post your information under Xamarin Developer Center or Bugzilla.

Answer (score 4):

From what I've observed, you will only see this exception if you have "break on all errors" turned on in Visual Studio / Xamarin Studio. The exception is thrown and caught by the mono https infrastructure.