# Azure Mobile Services in a PCL project that includes WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, portable-class-library, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to inlcude AzureMobileServices client in a PCL that includes WP8?

I used to have a PCL project that had it up until I upgraded it to VisualStudio 2013.

The required PCL is `profile78`: `.NET4.5`, `Windows Store apps (Win8)`, `WP8`, and the `Xamarin` twins.

I tried following [this recommendation from Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20228859/2126652) to reference the component's DLL directly, however the DLL was compiled for `profile7` (that does not include WP8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Make sure you are using at least version 1.1.5 of the Mobile Services NuGet package or Xamarin Component and you will be able to successfully use it from a PCL that includes WP8. For a tutorial on how to do this, see [here](https://github.com/paulbatum/mobile-services-xamarin-pcl).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like their nuget package only includes directories for Store, .Net 4.5, Wp8, and Portable-Store+.Net 4.5.  However if I ildasm the dll in the portable folder I see it was built for Profile78, which does support phone.

This looks like a bug with the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.nupkg nuspec authoring.