# Xamarin Forms PCL Project With Azure Mobile Service Error

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Azure Mobile Service in Xamarin Forms PCL Project but I encountered this error which I unable to solve it.

I had follow the official documentation by Azure at this [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-how-to-use-client-library/).

****Justification****

1. I already install Windows Azure Mobile Services from NuGet Packages and put `CurrentPlatform.Init();` & `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;`in every platforms.
2. Here's some tutorial that I found to implement Azure Mobile Service in Xamarin Forms. I had tried it out but still not working. Here is the link ---> 
   [link](http://blog.falafel.com/cross-platform-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-mobile-services/) 1, [link](https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Service/Models/ExistingDbContext.cs) 2, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226332/how-should-i-use-azure-mobile-services-with-pcl-or-without-it-now/30189970#30189970) 3

---

Here is my code for my project:

> Model

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace eRestaurant.Model
{
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "restaurantname")]
        public string RestaurantName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tag")]
        public string Tag { get; set; }

        public Restaurant()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

> Page

```
using eRestaurant.Model;
using eRestaurant.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace eRestaurant
{
    public class RestaurantPage : ContentPage
    {
        RestaurantViewModel viewModel = new RestaurantViewModel();
        ListView RestaurantListView = new ListView();

        public RestaurantPage()
        {
            Title = "Restaurants";
            Style = AppStyle.PageStyle;
            RestaurantListView.RowHeight = 40;

            RestaurantListView.ItemsSource = viewModel.restaurantData;
            RestaurantListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(RestaurantViewCell));
            Content = RestaurantListView;
        }
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices; //Azure Mobile Service
using System.Threading.Tasks; //For multithreading
using eRestaurant.Model;

namespace eRestaurant.ViewModel
{
    public class RestaurantViewModel
    {
        private IMobileServiceTable<Restaurant> restaurantTable;

        const string applicationURL = @"https://erestaurant.azure-mobile.net/";
        const string applicationKey = @"MyApplicationKey";

        MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient( applicationURL, applicationKey);


        public IEnumerable<Restaurant> restaurantData;

        public RestaurantViewModel()
        {
            GetData ();
        }

        public async void GetData(){
            restaurantTable = client.GetTable<Restaurant> ();
            restaurantData = await restaurantTable
            .Where (restaurant => restaurant.RestaurantName != null)
            .ToListAsync ();
        }

    }
}
```

> ViewCell As ItemTemplate

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using eRestaurant.Model;

namespace eRestaurant
{
    public class RestaurantViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        public RestaurantViewCell()
        {    
            Label restaurantName = new Label();
            restaurantName.Style = AppStyle.RestaurantLabelStyle;

            Label tag = new Label();
            tag.Style = AppStyle.TagLabelStyle;

            restaurantName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "RestaurantName");
            tag.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Tag");

            StackLayout nameLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children = { restaurantName, tag }
            };

            View = nameLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

Hereby is the error message that shown.

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  at Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at ... 1 more
  at Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: Error: Table 'Restaurant' does not exist.
  at at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004b>
  at at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0003b>
  at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1780/3518c4ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
  at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1780/3518c4ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1780/3518c4ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.061cf032-901c-4d7a-8b86-094723bf4132 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x00027>
  at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
  at at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
  at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at ... 4 more
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit - "table 'restaurant' does not exist" - are you sure it exists in your data?

Comment: I had the same issue, I had to manually create the table in the Azure UI as it doesn't create it on the fly.